# to get all the unique row according to particular column age from dataframe and delete the selected row

Tags: python-3.x

```
data4=[]
data5=[]
for i in ind:
    for j in (i+1,ind):
        if(data2['Age'][i] not in data2['Age'][j]):
           data4.append(data2.iloc[i])
    else:
        data5.append(data2.iloc[i])
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-f57e6df64c53> in `<module>`()
for i in ind:
    for j in (i+1,ind):
        if(data2['Age'][i] not in data2['Age'][j]):
            data4.append(data2.iloc[i])
        else:

TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Comment: ind=data2.index

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: Actually i did that but i can get only unique row, instead i want all the removed row to be deleted from original dataframe